# Efficient algorithm for replacing occurrences of tokens in an infinite stream

Tags: algorithm, stream, hashmap, hashtable

Given a map of strings, such as the following:

```
{'ABC': 'BCD', 'key': 'book',........}
```

And an infinite stream of text, such as:

```
"Sally had a key and a book with the ABC..."
```

What would be an efficient algorithm for replacing every token matching a key in the string map with its corresponding value?

Output:

```
"Sally had a book and a book with the BCD..."
```

Can one do any better than simply splitting the incoming tokens and querying the string map for containment (an O(1) operation)?

The code will reside on a webserver--the faster the user can get the converted output the better.

Comment: Define efficient?  Efficient memory wise?  I mean, you could have infinite memory, or petabytes of memory...  Efficient with CPU usage?  Or do we assume 1000 CPUs at 1000 petaflops?  Efficient with respect to time?  Efficient with respect to number of bytes used to write the code?

Comment: @atk, I am referring to the fastest algorithm. The stream can be held in a buffer of size N for each new token.

Comment: Splitting the input into tokens will be fast, and looking up entries in a hashmap will be fast. The only thing I can think of would be generalizing a string search algorithm such as [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth-Morris-Pratt_algorithm) for multiple strings, but that seems unlikely to be an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this without having to split the text into tokens, if you use the [Aho-Corasick string matching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm). Just have the output state on your leaf nodes return the replacement string.

This would likely be faster than splitting the text into tokens because you don't have to manage strings. It goes character-by-character. How much faster than using a hash table lookup is something you'd have to test. This would also be somewhat more difficult to implement than a simple hash table lookup.

Comment: Aho-Corasick (and friends) solve the problem of finding an unanchored substring. In this case, if I understand the OP correctly, the targets are single words which need to be matched on word alignments. Assuming the word separators can never appear in the target strings, AC simply reduces to a trie, which is even simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the algorithm you're looking for would be at least linear in terms of the number of tokens you're reading (since at best you'll be doing a constant number of operations over every token in your stream), so there'll be no improvements there, as I'm assuming there are no special redundancies or patterns in your input stream (which we could abuse for higher efficiency).

As for the map, the most efficient solution would probably be a Binary Search Tree over the keys of the map -- for a map of n items, we will only have to compare each token against log n different keys.

Without any further constraints on your problem, I doubt you'd get any more efficient than that -- worst-case complexity O(m log n) for m tokens and a map of n key-value pairs.

This is pretty good, but not awesome; so important question: Is there any way you can exploit your data?

Comment: do most languages implement hash map lookups using your bst method?

Comment: The input stream is akin to the output of an irc channel.

Comment: yes, that's the standard afaik, and if your input is an irc channel, then i'm guessing any possible optimization isn't worth the effort (mostly because I can't think of any :P)

Comment: @ramin: a hash map is a hash map. A BST map is a BST map. They're different algorithms. You can't implement one "with" the other one. (You can implement a map with either, or in other ways.) Hash maps are O(1) average, although if the hash algorithm is known they can be attacked. BSTs are always O(log n).

Comment: "if the hash algorithm is known they can be attacked." True, although probably irrelevant in this case because the hash table will be static. One would assume that the person implementing the program would select a good hash function, and since user data isn't being placed into the hash table, there's no attack surface.

Comment: @JimMischel: yes, the worst the attacker could do is force a string compare on every word, which shouldn't be terribly serious. I mentioned that in my actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guess that you're actually looking for an efficient solution in some higher-level language (node.js? python?); in general, if you're using such a language, you'd be well-advised to use a data-structure natively supported by that language, which would be a dictionary in Python and an object in Javascript. You probably already knew that.

If you were writing this in a lower-level language, you might want to choose an optimization which did not involve needlessly constructing string objects for each word, assuming that the vast majority of words will be unaffected by the substitution. One way to do this would be to use a character-by-character hashing algorithm, and compute it as you read the input characters, resetting every time you start a new word. When you reach the end of the word, you can check in average `O(1)` time if some target has that hash value. If not, just keep on reading. Periodically, you can flush the input buffer to the output, as long as you keep the current word.

If the targets are long (which is probably not the case), you could mostly avoid having to keep the current word by also storing the hash values of the prefixes (or some of the prefixes) of the target strings. Then when your input buffer is exhausted, you could check to see if the current hash value matches the hash value of one of the prefixes of the appropriate length. Doing an occasional check of this form can also solve the DoS attack based on deliberately creating hash collisions (although in your case, this is not so much a problem; all the attacker can do is force you to do a full text comparison of every word; they don't get to add their own words to the hash table.)

However, if I were writing this code in a low-level language like C, I'd probably put the target words into a trie, and track through the trie on every input character. As soon as there is no match in the trie, you can flush to the end of the current word; that is likely to happen very early in all non-matching words, perhaps even on their first character. Although a trie usually requires more storage than a hash map (and might even require more than a BST), there are storage compression techniques (if you can set the datastructure up in advance) and the ability to stop checking a word early is probably a win.

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned binary search and hash maps.  I suspect there's a slightly faster way, since you don't care about efficiency of memory usage.  Bucket sort the data you're looking for and compare to that.  This should speed up the comparison - instead of hashing the full input then matching, it's always looking for an exact match.

Given the map `{ABC, ABD, DEF, GH}` your data structure would look like...

```
pos:                     1                   2
     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6   <-- slot 26 is reserved for 
val: A 0 0 D 0 0 G 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0       "end of map token"
     |     |     |
     B     E     H   <-- sub buckets don't show all buckets as in the top level, but they
    / \    |     |       are all there.
   C   D   F     END
  /    |    \
END   END   END
```

Extend for the full character set you're accepting, or for 255 possible values per byte.  Then, when you get your input, you can test each character.

Example 1:

```
Input: ABC
    1: look up location 'Z' - 'A' = 0
    2: is there anything in this bucket? yes
    3: look in sub-buckets.  
    4: Is there anything in the 'Z'- 'B' bucket? yes
    5: look in sub buckets.
    6: Is there anything in the 'Z' - 'C' bucket? yes
    7: look in sub-buckets
    8: reached end of input token.  Is end of map bucket is marked? yes
    9: match found
```

Example 2:

```
Input: ABCD  (input token longer than closest match in map)
    1: look up location 'Z' - 'A' = 0
    2: is there anything in this bucket? yes
    3: look in sub-buckets.  
    4: Is there anything in the 'Z'- 'B' bucket? yes
    5: look in sub buckets.
    6: Is there anything in the 'Z' - 'C' bucket? yes
    7: look in sub-buckets
    8: Is there anything in the 'Z' - 'D' bucket? no
    9: match not found
```

Example 3:

```
Input: ABE
    1: look up location 'Z' - 'A' = 0
    2: is there anything in this bucket? yes
    3: look in sub-buckets.  
    4: Is there anything in the 'Z'- 'B' bucket? yes
    5: look in sub buckets.
    6: Is there anything in the 'Z' - 'E' bucket? no
    7: match found
```